# Legacy boot only available

Tags: uefi

I can't change to UEFI because BIOS is not saved. What should I do?

```
Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to sign-grub) and reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
sda2,
using the following options:        sda4/boot/efi,
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s  use-standard-efi-file

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

WindowsEFI detected. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or>

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________


Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.10 CurrentSession entry (sda4/efi/****/shim*>
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.

If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)
The boot of your PC is in BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode. You may want to retry after changing it to UEFI mode.
```

> ***WindowsEFI detected. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD
> (or>***

I am not able actually to do this due to the firmware settings not saved. Just BIOS(Legacy/CSM) is available.

On the other hand which I do not understand both OS (Ubuntu/Windows) are using UEFI, although the firmware settings are BIOS(Legacy). There is a blank screen flicker and then grub allows me to boot **only Ubuntu** (Windows - invalid signature). To boot Windows I have to go F9 / boot options / Boot Manager then grub menu list but from this menu, Windows **can** boot (Ubuntu too)

[image: description here]

As per Rod Smith:

> Upgrade your firmware—Some EFIs are badly broken, but hardware
> manufacturers occasionally release updates to their firmware. Thus, I
> recommend upgrading your firmware to the latest version available. If
> you know from forum posts or the like that your EFI is problematic,
> you should do this before installing Linux, because some problems will
> require extra steps to correct if the firmware is upgraded after the
> installation. On the other hand, upgrading firmware is always a bit
> risky, so holding off on such an upgrade may be best if you've heard
> good things about your manufacturer's EFI support.

My HP 15 Notebook (Insyde F.18) firmware settings are not saved and any attempt to upgrade fails consistently.

Comment: If Windows is installed in UEFI boot mode to gpt drive, then you have UEFI, not CSM/BIOS/Legacy. But how you boot live installer is only determined by your selection from the UEFI one time boot menu. And may depend on how you made Ubuntu live installer. Some tools like Rufus only create UEFI or only BIOS live installers. You want an UEFI installer. Do not boot in BIOS mode, do not use BIOS or you may break Windows.

Comment: Yes, Windows was installed in UEFI on converted to gpt /dev/sda, In order to boot Windows F9 boot options and such. Will not boot from grub menu (invalid signature).

Comment: As far as I remember ubuntu liveUSB was created with MultiWriter and Ubuntu MBR was converted to GPT after installation in order to install Windows 10.

Comment: If drive is gpt and you have Ubuntu in BIOS mode, you do not have to totally reinstall. Just reinstall grub in UEFI boot mode. Use Ubuntu live installer booted in UEFI mode, add Boot-Repair and from advanced options run the full reinstall of grub which installs the UEFI version of grub can changes a couple of settings to make install UEFI based.

Comment: the conundrum lays out in my initial question: I can't change to UEFI because BIOS is not saved. What should I do? If the firmware settings would have been saved I would have not been here...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by BIOS not saved or what setting is not saved. If Windows is UEFI, then UEFI must be setting. What brand/model system? Have you updated UEFI from vendor to latest available? How you boot flash drive is only determined by selection of UEFI:flash (where flash is name or label of flash drive) entry in UEFI one time boot menu. If no UEFI:flash entry then, flash drive not correctly configured for UEFI boot. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb

Comment: I added a screenshot for clarification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121337/discussion-between-brad-thompson-and-oldfred).

Comment: If UEFI Secure boot is on, you do not have Legacy/BIOS boot as an option. Ubuntu will install with UEFI Secure boot on, and work unless you also need proprietary drivers like nVidia or Wi-Fi. But with Secure boot on, you can only boot from UEFI menu, grub will not boot Windows unless Secure Boot is off. You may need to turn on allow USB boot or full USB support on some menu.